# Error every time I run 'lettuce' on python in VSCode

Tags: python, gherkin, lettuce

I am trying to run a simple test in lettuce (gherkin) but I can't pass the following error.
This is the test:

```
Feature: Go to google  

Scenario: Visit Google  
  Given I go to "http://www.google.com/"  
  When I fill in field with class "gsfi" with "testingbot"  
  Then I should see "testingbot.com" within 2 second
```

And this is the error:

```
PS C:\Users\\Documents\PYTHON\features\lettuce-browserstack> lettuce
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mihai.costache.DEA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts\lettuce-script.py", line 33, in <module>  
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('lettuce==0.2.23', 'console_scripts', 'lettuce')())  
  File "C:\Users\mihai.costache.DEA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts\lettuce-script.py", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()  
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))  
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 786, in exec_module  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 923, in get_code  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 853, in source_to_code  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed  
  File "C:\Users\mihai.costache.DEA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\lettuce\__init__.py", line 179  
    print "Error loading step definitions:\n", e
          ^  
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Error loading step definitions:\n", e)?
```

Is there a quick fix on this?
Thanks

Comment: lettuce is python2 - print didn't need parens then. I don't know how could you install it in python3, but it won't work without heavy modifications

Comment: I am having a similar issue with 'behave' which makes me wonder if it's deprecated as well or I am facing same error on my side. Is there something reliable for BDD development on Python ?